Disable resilience4j metrics sent to Prometheus
Since we are not using the resilience4j metrics, there are a lot of "spam" sent to prometheus. I want to somehow disable the metrics sent from resilience4j but until now no success. I tried out a few suggestions found searching in google also our friend the AIs didn't give me any useful solution.
Here is what I've tried so far:
Defining a java config class to block the metrics to the endpoint:
@Configuration
public class MicroMeterConfig {

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
        return registry -> registry.config().meterFilter(MeterFilter.deny(id -> {
            String uri = id.getTag("uri");
            return uri != null && uri.startsWith("/<placeholder>/prometheus");
        }));
    }

}

Tried to disable from the application.yml:
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    metrics:
      enabled: false

If I check the .../<placeholder>/prometheus endpoint I still see a lot of circuitbreaker metrics in the logs.
Any idea what can I try?
